# Is it wise to travel to Russia at this time?

Tags: international-travel, russia, nigerian-citizens

I had wanted to know something for the sake of clarity. Is travelling to Russia at this time a good idea? I mean for the sake of travel history judging by recent happenings and all happening in Russia.

Please I would like to know.

Comment: Nah, I am not from a western country, I am Nigerian.

Comment: you think the mob would ask you for your passport?

Comment: Asking if travel is ‘safe’ is inviting opinion-based answers https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask